# Using Jquery tabs isn't working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tabs, jquery-ui-tabs

I have 3 different graphs I want to put in tabs and open when selected upon. I used a boostrap elements to make 3 of the graphs. I followed along the Jquery site and used that example and it isn't working how it should. For Example, when I click Tab 1 I want Graph one to appear. I've posted the code below.

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
      
    $( '#tabs' ).tabs();
      
   });
```

```css
.col-md-1{       padding: 10px;
                 border:1px solid white;
         }
#size {    padding: 10px;
            border:1px solid white;
            }
#page{padding-bottom: 100px; 
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
  <title>CS2100 Project 3</title>
    
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css">
    
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/style.css">
        
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"> </script>
    
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  
    

  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- Optional theme -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="project3.css">

  <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
  <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
         
</head>
    
  <body>
        <div id="main">
    <div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#part1">PART 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#part2">PART 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#part3">PART 3</a></li>
  </ul>
      
        
    
      <div class="container" id="part1">
          <h3>PART 1: 7-Day Forecast (HTML)</h3>
        <table class="table table-hover table-bordered text-center">
           <tbody>
            <tr class="bg-primary text-primary">
               <th class="text-center">Forecast</th>
               <th class="text-center">Thursday</th>
               <th class="text-center">Friday</th>
               <th class="text-center">Saturday</th>
               <th class="text-center">Sunday</th>
               <th class="text-center">Monday</th>
               <th class="text-center">Tuesday</th>
               <th class="text-center">Wednesday</th>
            </tr>

            <tr>
               <td>High</td>
                <td>88</td>
                <td>81</td>
                <td>75</td>
                <td>83</td>
                <td>87</td>
                <td>90</td>
                <td>91</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
               <td>Low</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>59</td>
                <td>52</td>
                <td>57</td>
                <td>59</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>65</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td>Precip</td>
                <td>0%</td>
                <td>50%</td>
                <td>40%</td>
                <td>10%</td>
                <td>0%</td>
                <td>0%</td>
                <td>0%</td>
            </tr>

            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      
      
      
      <div id="part2">
        <div class="container" id="page">
     <h3>PART 2: 7-Day Forecast (Bootstrap Grid)</h3>
     
           <div class="row bg-primary text-primary">
               <div class="col-md-1 text-center">Forecast</div>
               <div class="col-md-1 text-center">Thursday</div>
               <div class="col-md-1 text-center">Friday</div>
               <div class="col-md-1 text-center">Saturday</div>
               <div class="col-md-1 text-center">Sunday</div>
               <div class="col-md-1 text-center">Monday</div>
               <div class="col-md-1 text-center">Tuesday</div>
               <div class="col-md-1 text-center">Wednesday</div> 
               <div class="col-md-4 text-center" id="color"></div> 
            </div>
            
            <div class="row bg-info text-info">
               <div class="col-md-1 text-center">0</div>
               <div class="col-md-1 text-center">88</div>
               <div class="col-md-1 text-center">81</div>
               <div class="col-md-1 text-center">75</div>
               <div class="col-md-1 text-center">83</div>
               <div class="col-md-1 text-center">87</div>
               <div class="col-md-1 text-center">90</div>
               <div class="col-md-1 text-center">91</div>
               <div class="col-md-4 text-center" id="color"></div> 
            </div>
            
             <div class="row bg-info text-info">
               <div class="col-md-1 text-center">Low</div>
               <div class="col-md-1 text-center">61</div>
               <div class="col-md-1 text-center">59</div>
               <div class="col-md-1 text-center">52</div>
               <div class="col-md-1 text-center">57</div>
               <div class="col-md-1 text-center">59</div>
               <div class="col-md-1 text-center">63</div>
               <div class="col-md-1 text-center">65</div> 
               <div class="col-md-4 text-center" id="color"></div> 
            </div>
            
            <div class="row bg-info text-info">
               <div class="col-md-1 text-center">Precip</div>
               <div class="col-md-1 text-center">0%</div>
               <div class="col-md-1 text-center">50%</div>
               <div class="col-md-1 text-center">40%</div>
               <div class="col-md-1 text-center">10%</div>
               <div class="col-md-1 text-center">0%</div>
               <div class="col-md-1 text-center">0%</div>
               <div class="col-md-1 text-center">0%</div> 
               <div class="col-md-4 text-center" id="color"></div> 
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
            
       
      
<div id="part3">  
 <div class="container" id="page">
     <h3>PART 3: TCP PACKET STRUCTURE</h3>
     
   <div class="row bg-primary text-primary">
  <div class="col-md-1 text-right" id="size">Byte#</div>
  <div class="col-md-3 text-center" id="size">+0</div>
  <div class="col-md-3 text-center" id="size">+1</div>
  <div class="col-md-3 text-center" id="size">+2</div>
  <div class="col-md-2 text-center" id="size">+3</div>
 
   </div>
     
     <div class="row bg-info text-info">
  <div class="col-md-1 text-right" id="size">0</div>
  <div class="col-md-5 text-center" id="size">Source Port</div>
  <div class="col-md-6 text-center" id="size">Destination Port</div>     
     </div>
     
     <div class="row bg-info text-info">
  <div class="col-md-1 text-right" id="size">4</div>
  <div class="col-md-11 text-center" id="size">Sequence Number</div>
     </div>
     
      <div class="row bg-info text-info">
  <div class="col-md-1 text-right" id="size">8</div>
  <div class="col-md-11 text-center" id="size">ACK Number</div>
      </div>
     
      <div class="row bg-info text-info">
  <div class="col-md-1 text-right" id="size">8</div>
  <div class="col-md-1 text-center" id="size">Offset</div>
  <div class="col-md-1 text-center" id="size">Reserved</div>
  <div class="col-md-5 text-center" id="size">Flags</div>
  <div class="col-md-4 text-center" id="size">Window Size</div>
      </div>
     
     <div class="row bg-info text-info">
  <div class="col-md-1 text-right" id="size">16</div>
  <div class="col-md-5 text-center" id="size">Checksum</div>
  <div class="col-md-6 text-center" id="size">Urgent Pointer</div>
     </div>
     
     <div class="row bg-info text-info">
  <div class="col-md-1 text-right" id="size">20-56</div>
  <div class="col-md-11 text-center" id="size">Options</div>
     </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 </div>
</div> 
 


       
   



    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
     

   
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is with the additionally declared jQuery library at the bottom of the page:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"</script>
```

As well, you have not included the jQuery UI library:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
      
    $( '#tabs' ).tabs();
      
   });
```

```css
.col-md-1{       padding: 10px;
                 border:1px solid white;
         }
#size {    padding: 10px;
            border:1px solid white;
            }
#page{padding-bottom: 100px; 
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
  <title>CS2100 Project 3</title>
    
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css">
    
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/style.css">
        
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"> </script>
    
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- Optional theme -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="project3.css">

  <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
  <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
         
</head>
    
  <body>
        <div id="main">
    <div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#part1">PART 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#part2">PART 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#part3">PART 3</a></li>
  </ul>
      
        
    
      <div class="container" id="part1">
          <h3>PART 1: 7-Day Forecast (HTML)</h3>
        <table class="table table-hover table-bordered text-center">
           <tbody>
            <tr class="bg-primary text-primary">
               <th class="text-center">Forecast</th>
               <th class="text-center">Thursday</th>
               <th class="text-center">Friday</th>
               <th class="text-center">Saturday</th>
               <th class="text-center">Sunday</th>
               <th class="text-center">Monday</th>
               <th class="text-center">Tuesday</th>
               <th class="text-center">Wednesday</th>
            </tr>

            <tr>
               <td>High</td>
                <td>88</td>
                <td>81</td>
                <td>75</td>
                <td>83</td>
                <td>87</td>
                <td>90</td>
                <td>91</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
               <td>Low</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>59</td>
                <td>52</td>
                <td>57</td>
                <td>59</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>65</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td>Precip</td>
                <td>0%</td>
                <td>50%</td>
                <td>40%</td>
                <td>10%</td>
                <td>0%</td>
                <td>0%</td>
                <td>0%</td>
            </tr>

            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      
      
      
      <div id="part2">
        <div class="container" id="page">
     <h3>PART 2: 7-Day Forecast (Bootstrap Grid)</h3>
     
           <div class="row bg-primary text-primary">
               <div class="col-md-1 text-center">Forecast</div>
               <div class="col-md-1 text-center">Thursday</div>
               <div class="col-md-1 text-center">Friday</div>
               <div class="col-md-1 text-center">Saturday</div>
               <div class="col-md-1 text-center">Sunday</div>
               <div class="col-md-1 text-center">Monday</div>
               <div class="col-md-1 text-center">Tuesday</div>
               <div class="col-md-1 text-center">Wednesday</div> 
               <div class="col-md-4 text-center" id="color"></div> 
            </div>
            
            <div class="row bg-info text-info">
               <div class="col-md-1 text-center">0</div>
               <div class="col-md-1 text-center">88</div>
               <div class="col-md-1 text-center">81</div>
               <div class="col-md-1 text-center">75</div>
               <div class="col-md-1 text-center">83</div>
               <div class="col-md-1 text-center">87</div>
               <div class="col-md-1 text-center">90</div>
               <div class="col-md-1 text-center">91</div>
               <div class="col-md-4 text-center" id="color"></div> 
            </div>
            
             <div class="row bg-info text-info">
               <div class="col-md-1 text-center">Low</div>
               <div class="col-md-1 text-center">61</div>
               <div class="col-md-1 text-center">59</div>
               <div class="col-md-1 text-center">52</div>
               <div class="col-md-1 text-center">57</div>
               <div class="col-md-1 text-center">59</div>
               <div class="col-md-1 text-center">63</div>
               <div class="col-md-1 text-center">65</div> 
               <div class="col-md-4 text-center" id="color"></div> 
            </div>
            
            <div class="row bg-info text-info">
               <div class="col-md-1 text-center">Precip</div>
               <div class="col-md-1 text-center">0%</div>
               <div class="col-md-1 text-center">50%</div>
               <div class="col-md-1 text-center">40%</div>
               <div class="col-md-1 text-center">10%</div>
               <div class="col-md-1 text-center">0%</div>
               <div class="col-md-1 text-center">0%</div>
               <div class="col-md-1 text-center">0%</div> 
               <div class="col-md-4 text-center" id="color"></div> 
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
            
       
      
<div id="part3">  
 <div class="container" id="page">
     <h3>PART 3: TCP PACKET STRUCTURE</h3>
     
   <div class="row bg-primary text-primary">
  <div class="col-md-1 text-right" id="size">Byte#</div>
  <div class="col-md-3 text-center" id="size">+0</div>
  <div class="col-md-3 text-center" id="size">+1</div>
  <div class="col-md-3 text-center" id="size">+2</div>
  <div class="col-md-2 text-center" id="size">+3</div>
 
   </div>
     
     <div class="row bg-info text-info">
  <div class="col-md-1 text-right" id="size">0</div>
  <div class="col-md-5 text-center" id="size">Source Port</div>
  <div class="col-md-6 text-center" id="size">Destination Port</div>     
     </div>
     
     <div class="row bg-info text-info">
  <div class="col-md-1 text-right" id="size">4</div>
  <div class="col-md-11 text-center" id="size">Sequence Number</div>
     </div>
     
      <div class="row bg-info text-info">
  <div class="col-md-1 text-right" id="size">8</div>
  <div class="col-md-11 text-center" id="size">ACK Number</div>
      </div>
     
      <div class="row bg-info text-info">
  <div class="col-md-1 text-right" id="size">8</div>
  <div class="col-md-1 text-center" id="size">Offset</div>
  <div class="col-md-1 text-center" id="size">Reserved</div>
  <div class="col-md-5 text-center" id="size">Flags</div>
  <div class="col-md-4 text-center" id="size">Window Size</div>
      </div>
     
     <div class="row bg-info text-info">
  <div class="col-md-1 text-right" id="size">16</div>
  <div class="col-md-5 text-center" id="size">Checksum</div>
  <div class="col-md-6 text-center" id="size">Urgent Pointer</div>
     </div>
     
     <div class="row bg-info text-info">
  <div class="col-md-1 text-right" id="size">20-56</div>
  <div class="col-md-11 text-center" id="size">Options</div>
     </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 </div>
</div> 
 


       
   



    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->

    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```